# How to set the wallpaper using cron

Tags: linux, cron, archlinux, xfce

I have this script and it works:

```
#!/bin/bash
xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop \
-p /backdrop/screen0/monitor0/workspace0/last-image \
-s /home/user/Pictures/wallpaper.png
```

But the **cronie** does not want to execute it (**notify-send** works good).

There is an error in the logs:

```
CMDOUT (Failed to init libxfconf: Using X11 for dbus-daemon autolaunch was disabled at compile time, set your DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS instead.)
```

I tried to use `export $(dbus-launch)` in my **.bashrc**, but this did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues using cron and accessing the X display/cookie file.

There is a file named "$machine_id-$display_number" where

- $machine_id is a random number stored in /var/lib/dbus/machine-id
- $display_number is the X Display number, which means the $DISPLAY (which is :$display_number or :$display_number.$screen_number).

This file (let's refer it as "dbus file"), is stored in ~/.dbus/session-bus
and contains information about DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS and DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID (it's a text file).

You will need to export those 2 variables from the file.

```
dbus_session_file=~/.dbus/session-bus/$(cat /var/lib/dbus/machine-id)-0
if [ -e "$dbus_session_file" ]; then
  . "$dbus_session_file"
  export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID
xconf-query ...
fi
```

NOTES:

1. I assume you are not logged in as root (and that your cron is under root privileges).
2. Beware that there's no guarantee that the user is still logged in. If he is logged out, the dbus daemon will be unavailable.
3. I wanted to explain what happens in the background. But there are easier ways to find the PID of a process in the desktop session, and obtain the dbus address from its environment

   export $( < /proc/$pid/environ tr \0 \n | grep -E '^DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=')

Comment: My `/var/lib/dbus` dir was empty and i run this command: `dbus-uuidgen > /var/lib/dbus/machine-id` but i have no `~/.dbus` in my home dir. Is it a problem?

Comment: I'm just looking for a quick solution without diving into the d-bus )))

Comment: Could you add this 'echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS > ~/a.txt' to the cron? and tell me what is written there?

Comment: {start_crontab}
@reboot echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS > ~/dbus.txt
{\n}
@reboot echo 'test' >> ~/dbus.txt
{end_crontab}
... and after rebooting cron printed only `test` string

Comment: Dbus-launch uses either ~/.dbus dir or X display in order to get its session's configuration. I'm not sure where yours is taken from if not from this hidden dir..

Comment: command `echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` in the terminal printed `unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-fIYoMa53YP,guid=25a42f1f8476b2606d02f1d258fc6433`

Comment: but `/tmp/dbus-fIYoMa53YP` - is not a file in my fs

Comment: No, ignore that file. It's because you ran it from the terminal

Comment: same problem in my Debian with `/backdrop/screen0/monitor0/image-path` - xfconf-query works fine only when i use terminal... sad...

Comment: What os do you use? And what the second problem you said?

Comment: i use Arch Linux with actual updates and now i tried to set wallpaper in my laptop (Debian 8.7) with `/backdrop/screen0/monitor0/image-path` - it is works, but only by terminal - it's ignored by anacron (like cronie in my Arch)

Comment: but i found `~/.dbus/session-bus/` with 2 files )))

Comment: What files are there?

Comment: There are two session files in my Debian and i can use `"~/.dbus/session-bus/$(cat /var/lib/dbus/machine-id)-0"`. What i did? By adding line `echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS > ~/dbus.txt` in my script after including this file i get this value. Note that i have different values. I suppose that dbus session started more than once. I meen that value DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in `~/dbus.txt !== ~/.dbus/session-bus/...`

Answer (score 1):

I do it with `feh` through cronie on Arch as well

I'm using a one liner, which takes a random picture from a given folder and addresses it with `DISPLAY:=0` to the current display

`#!/bin/bash
file=$(find ~/Pictures/.wallpaper/ -type f | shuf -n1) && DISPLAY=:0 feh --bg-scale $file`

Comment: Feh is not working. I don't know why. Silent. By terminal also

Comment: the command `feh --bg-scale path/to/example/pic.jpg` doesn't work?

Comment: I'm using the suggestion with nitrogen: `DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/nitrogen --random --set-scaled $HOME/img/`. It works.

Answer (score 0):

in the bash script do this (so it can be successful in crontab):

```
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$UID/bus
xfconf-query ...
```

from https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1706208#p1706208